# Comparison of string (read from file) in python not working

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

I have a text file (buy_sell.txt) containing the word "`BOUGHT`". No new lines or spaces.

When I try to check if the contents of the file ("`BOUGHT`") are equal to "BOUGHT" it evaluates to false!

```
  f = open("buy_sell.txt", "r")
  print(f.read())
  if(f.read() == "BOUGHT"):
    print('works')
```

How do I get the code to evaluate to true?

Comment: The second `f.read()` will give you `''`.

Comment: The cursor of the file is at the end after you used `f.read()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your file is a single line, you just need to `read` it once:

```
f = open("buy_sell.txt", "r")
if f.read() == "BOUGHT":
    print("works")
```

If you would like to reuse this value later on, just assign it to a variable:

```
f = open("buy_sell.txt", "r")
my_value = f.read()
if my_value == "BOUGHT":
    print("works")

if my_value != "BOUGHT": 
   print("Must be SOLD!")
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought there was an invisible character read from the file or something